# Recommendations on a way to optimize multiple joins. Is it bad practice to use another table to compile data using database triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to create custom fields on employees. These fields would be things like First Name, Last Name etc.

I'm required to optimize this to work for 10,000 employees with 200 fields.

Right now I have an "employee" table, a "field" table and pivot table ("employee_field").  The pivot table stores the employee's data for each of the fields in the nullable column with the data type required for that field. It also contains the employee id and the field id.

I'm finding that joining these tables takes about 0.5 seconds to load 500 employees with 50 fields.

I'm about to try creating another table that keeps all of the joined data I need for the application. This would basically be a table that contains the employee id, field id, the field label, the formatted data, and the field type alias.  This table would be kept up to date using database triggers.

**Question:** Am I following the best practice for doing this kind of join, and is there any way to optimize this for reading this data?

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, I've went over all the indexes and all IDs are indexed with foreign key references.

Answer (score 1):

You have an entity-attribute-value data model.  There is nothing *per se* wrong with such a model, but it seems like overkill for your purposes.

MySQL should be able to readily handle a table with 200 columns.  My recommendation is to eschew the joins and just define the table that you need.

Now, your situation might be a bit more fluid.  Perhaps new columns need to be added.  In this scenario, new fields are fine . . . if adding them is infrequent and they apply to all employees.

If you frequently need to handle new fields, or different employees have different subsets of fields.  If this is the case, then I would recommend a hybrid model.  Put the dozens of common fields into a single table and then build a more flexible EAV model for new attributes.

Comment: It's needs to be dynamic.  The fields are customizable by the app's end user, so the fields all need to be stored this way (unless there would be a better way).

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I've come to the conclusion that it has something to do with my apps binding to SQL and not the SQL schema.